# Force required to rotate a rod around an axis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

The problem I'm trying to solve is:

How much force, momentarily applied to the rod, is required to rotate it around an axis by a given degree? Assuming there is friction applied at the axis (`T_f`).

[image]

Rod mass `m` and length `r` are known, the rod is completely stiff.

I assume that I have to construct a differential equation to solve this problem, but I'm not sure how.

A separate question would be to how to experimentally measure or approximate the friction torque since it isn't really known.

Comment: Hi Andrey and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Note that as it stands the problem is wrongly phrased. My guess is that you're really asking what [impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_(physics)), i.e. what change of momentum, needs to be applied to the rod. Impulse is force times time not just force.

Comment: @JohnRennie This is not technically a homework question, although I see how it might appear as such. In any case, I don't see how it matters since looking at the links you've provided there doesn't seem to be a ban on homework-like questions.

Comment: The force is not a function of rotational displacement. The same force can be used to move the rod 10° as well as 100°. The question should be about the work required instead.

Comment: @andreyg There's no ban, but it is expected that you show what you've tried so far. You've done some thinking already; can you show what calculations you've tried? Thanks.

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple rotational problems the torque $\tau$ to cause acceleration about an axis of rotation is given by:

$$\tau=I\ddot{\theta},$$

where $I$ is the [Inertial moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia) of the object and $\ddot{\theta}$ the *angular acceleration*:

$$\ddot{\theta}=\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}.$$

In addition, in your problem there is frictional torque $T_f$ to overcome, so:

$$\tau=I\ddot{\theta}+T_f$$

This torque will be supplied by the force $F$, acc.:

$$Fr=I\ddot{\theta}+T_f$$

Find $F$ from that expression with a suitable expression for $I$ (see link).

If we set $\ddot{\theta}=0$, then:

$$F=\frac{T_f}{r},$$

which would be the force to just balance the frictional torque $T_f$. Increasing $F$ very slightly would then result in slow rotation.

Comment: Does this equation apply if the force is applied momentarily at the start of the movement?

Comment: Yes but 'momentarily' might not get you very far! The amount of rotation (change in $\theta$) can be found from:$\Delta \theta=\frac{\ddot{\theta}t^2}{2}$, with $t$ the amount of time you applied the force $F$.

Comment: @andreyg: small edit made.